# Modifying Text Line Mask Animation on Scroll to on Reveal

Tags: jquery, animation, text, text-mask

Basically, I saw this stunning effect from t.ricks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvqSioowCRc

[image]

I want to make the same effect when the text scroll into view, instead of play the effect while scrolling the page

In short, my question is: 
I would like to play the animation when the text is "appear" instead of "scroll".

The code is below:

```js
let typeSplit;
// Split the text up
function runSplit() {
  typeSplit = new SplitType(".split-lines", {
    types: "lines, words"
  });
  $(".line").append("<div class='line-mask'></div>");
  createAnimation();
}
runSplit();
// Update on window resize
let windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  if (windowWidth !== $(window).innerWidth()) {
    windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    typeSplit.revert();
    runSplit();
  }
});

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

function createAnimation() {
  $(".line").each(function (index) {
    let tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: $(this),
        // trigger element - viewport
        start: "top center",
        end: "bottom center",
        scrub: 1
      }
    });
    tl.to($(this).find(".line-mask"), {
      width: "0%",
      duration: 1
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.split-lines {
  display: block;
  margin: 25% auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  width: 50%;
}
.line {
  position: relative;
}
.line-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.65;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/split-type"></script>

<div class="split-lines">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept, I would use, is to set to each line a different animation delay and then trigger the animation event, for example by setting the `.line-mask` width to `0%`.

```html
<div class="split-lines">
  <div class="line" style="display: block">
    Lorem Ipsum is
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%; transition: width 0.2s ease-in;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block">
    simply dummy text of
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%; transition: width 0.4s ease-in;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block">
    the printing and
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%; transition: width 0.6s ease-in;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example with the same concept, it doesn't matter if the delay is inline style or as `nth-child` CSS element:

[image]

```js
let splitLines = document.getElementsByClassName('split-lines');

startAnimation = function() {
  let classes = splitLines[0].classList;
  classes.remove('animate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    classes.add('animate');
  }, 500);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  startAnimation()
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.split-lines {
  display: block;
  margin: 5% auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  width: 50%;
}
.split-lines.animate .line-mask {
  width: 0% !important;
  transition: width 2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.4, 1);
}
.line {
  position: relative;
}
.line-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.65;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(1) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(2) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(3) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(4) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(5) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 1.0s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(6) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 1.2s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(7) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 1.4s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(8) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 1.6s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(9) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 1.8s;
}
.animate .line:nth-child(10) .line-mask {
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
a {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #444;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 11px;
}
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-lines">
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">Lorem</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">is</div>
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">simply</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">dummy</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">text</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">of</div>
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">the</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">printing</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">and</div>
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">typesetting</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">industry.</div>
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">Lorem</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">has</div>
    <div class="line-mask" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">been</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">the</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">industry's</div>
    <div class="line-mask"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">standard</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">dummy</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">text</div>
    <div class="line-mask"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">ever</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">since</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">the</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">1500s,</div>
    <div class="line-mask"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">when</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">an</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">unknown</div>
    <div class="line-mask"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line" style="display: block; text-align: start; width: 100%;">
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">printer</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">took</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">a</div>
    <div class="word" style="display: inline-block;">galley</div>
    <div class="line-mask"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<a onclick="startAnimation()" href="#">Restart animation</a>
```

---

ps: Using a [SCSS `for` loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) you write really fast the `nth-child` CSS code eg.:

```scss
$anim_start: 0.0;
$anim_gap: 0.2;
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    .line::nth-child(#{$i}) .line-mask {
        transition-delay: #{$anim_start + ($anim_gap * ($i - 1))}s;
    }
}
```

Here is the example with SCSS on [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/wittich-the-sasster/pen/ExLBomj).